# Send new value to Google Tag Manager through dataLayer from fancybox (ajax)

Tags: fancybox, google-tag-manager

I'm using GTM and I need sending several values for each web/product.

In a specific web I've a lightbox to get some data from user and need to send a "conversionValue" with a different value when the user finish the task.

When I try to do this by using dataLayer.push it just add a new object to the original dataLayer (as it is in a fancybox loaded by ajax, not iframe, it gets the "parent page" dataLayer), so I get a dataLayer with many objects and only the last one has the correct "conversionValue".

The problem is, if I try to use this variable from GTM, it gets the first object to look for the conversionValue...

Should I clear the dataLayer before pushing new objects? Am I doing it wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading about Google Tag Manager, it doesn't matter if you add new objects to dataLayer because their variables can't be readed from GTM the same way as you read them for the first time.

You have to read new values by defining events.